# Create a WiFi access point that shares the Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, network-bridge, wireless-access-point

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3. The idea of what I'm trying to achieve is represented by the following schema:

```
                             Raspberry Pi
             WiFi        ┌──────bridge──────┐     Ethernet
   Laptop <~.~.~.~.~.~.~>│ (wlan0)br0(eth0) │<---------------->Device
      \                              /                           /
   192.168.1.200             192.168.1.1               192.168.1.10
```

Basically the sensors on the device collects data and the Raspberry runs a MERN app that displays them and they are accessible to anyone connected to the WiFi access point.

I've achieved this configuration in the Raspbian OS following [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94142/how-to-connect-a-ethernet-devicehaving-its-own-static-i-p-and-netmask-wireless?rq=1&newreg=f58ba7f463a3466584426ace4ae0e4b0) but I need to do something equivalent on Ubuntu Server 18.04 because I need the latest version of MongoDB for the device store the data.

`wifi-ap` [(details here)](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/installation) works efficiently in order to create the access point but it doesn't bridge the Ethernet connection to the device. I've tried giving and static IP in the `netplan` and messing with the `dhcp` but it still didn't work.

Is there a way to make the the brigde using the `wifi-ap`? What am I missing?
Or there is a way to replicate [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94142/how-to-connect-a-ethernet-devicehaving-its-own-static-i-p-and-netmask-wireless?rq=1&newreg=f58ba7f463a3466584426ace4ae0e4b0) in the Ubuntu Server 18.04? Or any other method which allows me to make it work?

Thanks in advance.